# About collections of questions at SE which are "solution manuals" to some book

Tags: discussion, allowed-questions

This is closely related to this question: [Creating a solutions manual within a single math.SE question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11971/creating-a-solutions-manual-within-a-single-math-se-question)

The difference is that I am asking about possibility of posting exercises from some book as a separate questions. (Which, I assume, is ok.) But the main question is whether it would be possible to create somewhere on the MSE also "an index" linking number of exercises to questions where there are answered.

I can imagine several possibilities:

- Creating such a list off-site; somewhere on your personal site, blog, etc. The disadvantage is that probably most such solutions will need one person to maintain it. (It is not collaborative.)
- If you want it on MSE, perhaps you could do such thing in your "about me". This doesn't seem to be a good solution. Again only one person can edit it. I do not know what is the length limit for "about me". Perhaps more reasonable thing to do put there a link to another website, where you have collected links to solutions.
- You could create a chatroom dedicated to a single book. In the chatroom you can mention that Exercise 3.1.2 is solved in the question on the main site and add a link. The main disadvantage is that this would be very disorganized. But if you were able to find several people who are interested in the same book, a chatroom could help you to coordinate you efforts. (And even if you decide not to post the exercises and solutions on the MSE, if you have some other people reading the same book, it can be very useful for you that you can discuss the things you learned there with them.)
- The simplest solution would be to collecd such list of links as a CW answer to a question. (Or several CW answers, one for this chapter.) In this way we obtain a collection of solutions, which will be very probably incomplete, but this is a way to do this collaboratively. (When a user finds or creates a question, which is an exercise from the particular book, or is equivalent to such exercise, they can add a new link to the CW answer.)

---

Let me elaborate a little more on the last possibility.

If a question would be: *"Are there some solution manuals/solution collections to this book available?"* Suppose someone posts a CW answer saying something like: *Apart from the links mentioned in other answers, you can find many exercises from this book solved here on this site. I will list here links to the solutions on this site which I am aware of." (Perhaps apart from exercises other questions related to the particular book could be listed there; for example questions mentioning possible typos, questions asking about clarification of some particular proof in the book, etc.)  I personally would consider it a valid answer; since it answers (at least partially) the original questions.

So main question I am asking here is this:

> Would questions asking about collections of solutions/solution manuals for books be ok here on MSE. Would it be ok to have there as one of the answers list of links to question on MSE, which are exercises from that particular book?

---

Some further comments:

This is very similar to my previous question: [Are questions about existence of a solution manual to a book allowed on MSE?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11323/are-questions-about-existence-of-a-solution-manual-to-a-book-allowed-on-mse) The only difference is that now I have also mentioned a possibility of adding list of solutions available on MSE. Since the most upvoted answer on that question says that such questions are not welcome here, probably questions of this type would not be well-received either. But we will see what comes up in the discussion for this question.

Another similar question is this: ["Hint book" for arbitrary books (Rudin, Hungerford, etc.)?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11703/hint-book-for-arbitrary-books-rudin-hungerford-etc)

As I have mentioned in my answer [here](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/9142/centralized-solutions-to-textbook-problems-considered-harmful/9151#9151) there already exist several books for which many questions on this site are in fact exercises taken from those books.

There is a [commutative algebra chatroom](http://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/info/2674/commutative-algebra). It is now frozen, since it was inactive for a long time. It was not devoted exclusively to Atiyah-MacDonald, but I'd say it was not negligible part of the activity in this chatroom. See the [room topic](http://chat.stackexchange.com/transcript/message/4806840#4806840) in one stage of the history of that chatroom. So this is somewhat similar to the chatroom solution I have mentioned before.

At the moment at one of the seminars I am reading Apostol's Analytic Number Theory together with some students. We also try to do the exercises. For some questions I have tried whether I can find them as questions on MSE. (I did not do this for all questions, I just wanted to experiment, whether I will be able to find the exercises here. So far I'd say the success rate is above 10%; it might get higher if I tried to locate *all* of the questions. But I suppose it will sink lower when we get to more advanced chapters.) I have put the links that I have found to the forum I have created for our seminar. So this is an example of the "off-site" solution. (And I would not be surprised if there were some other such collections.)

I have asked before about posting list of links to other questions as an answer: [Would "organizer posts" be useful/welcome here?](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/3967/would-organizer-posts-be-useful-welcome-here) But this was for an entirely different purpose - mainly to avoid duplicates. (I hope that the opinion of the community have not changed for that one.)

Comment: I suppose that there is a possibility that this will be closed as a duplicate of [Don Larynx's question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11703/) or some other questions. However, I have tried to elaborate some things from that posts in more detail. If it is getting on some people nerves that there were several questions about solution manuals, I do apologize. But after reading [Arthur Fischer's question](http://meta.math.stackexchange.com/questions/11971/) I felt that this would be a very natural continuation of that discussion, but a separate question would be better.

Comment: I wouldn't mind a CW thread on Meta labelled solution manuals (maybe grouped by subject) But to reduce noise, there should be as few lists as possible (i.e. not one per book) If the answers contain a fixed-format description (maybe Author - Book, Chapter Exercise or something), the search feature should do well in finding them.